# Solve "File too big !" message on hg view output

Tags: mercurial

I am using hgview (http://www.hgview.org/). In some cases a diff of a file is not shown, but instead only a "File too big !" line is present.
Is there a way to somehow configure this limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just discovered the 'Display heavy file' icon on the taskbar of hgview...